# How change DateTime display format to use my function?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, datetime, datagridview

I use Microsoft SQL server to save and retrieve `DateTime`. But in our culture, users use Persian date time. So i wrote a extension method `ToPersianDateString(this DateTime dt)` to display users the correct Persian date instate of Gregorian date.

Problem occurs when `DataGridView` want's to display data or after user edits Persian date value. Is there a way to specify `DataGridView` to call my function for date time columns and after user edits date time column, converts it to Gregorian date time?

I also have a static function for converting to Gregorian date:

```
static DateTime ToGregorianDate(string persianDate);
```

I'm using Linq to SQL as ORM and my sample form is like this:

```
public class PeopleForm : Form
{
    DataContext context = new DataContext();

    public PeopleForm()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
        datagridview1.DataSource = context.People;
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(...)
    {
        try{
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show(...);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `DataGridView.CellFormatting` Event?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if it's Persian Date Column
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "PersianDate") //PersianDate == Your Date Column Name
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
             e.Value = ToGregorianDate(e.Value);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but it's only half of way, where and when reconvert data after edition to Gregorian date time?

Comment: you could use CellEndEdit Event and convert the changed value to your required date format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit.aspx

Comment: Thanks. It works. But every time I move my mouse over a cell this event is triggered. Is there any better event for this purpose?